# Glassfish Connection Pool - java.sql.SQLException: Connection closed

Tags: jsf-2, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling, glassfish-4

I'm using for a web project JSF2 with **Oracle Glassfish Server Open Source Edition 4.0** and  **Oracle Database 11g (Version 11.2.0-1.0)**. 
The server and database are running on the same windows machine.
A connection pool managed the connections to the database.

Does anybody know why I **sometimes** get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection closed
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.checkValidity(ConnectionHolder.java:766)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.commit(ConnectionHolder.java:243)
    at de.mydomain.myproject.Hl7MessageHandler.run(Hl7MessageHandler.java:123)
    ...
```

Or sometimes this one:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:5675)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:5735)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.commit(ConnectionHolder.java:244)
    at de.mydomain.myproject.Hl7MessageHandler.run(Hl7MessageHandler.java:123)
    ...
```

*The Database Class:*

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {     
    Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
    DataSource datasSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/Oracle"); 
    Connection connnection = datasSource.getConnection();
    return connnection; 
}
```

*Request handling in the servlet:*

```
public IResponseSendable<String> run(String hl7MsgString, boolean publishErrorToDB) {

    // ... do something

    try {
        con = Database.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException conExc) {

        return generateAck(true, conExc.getMessage(), hl7MsgString);        
    }

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false); 
        process();
        con.commit();
    } catch (HL7Exception | SQLException pe) {
        logger.error(...);

        // Exceptionhandling...

        try { 
            con.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException rollbackExc) { 
            logger.error(...);
        }           
        return generateAck(true, pe.getMessage(),hl7MsgString, _log);
    }
    finally {

        try { 
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { 
            logger.error(...);
        }
    }
    return generateAck(false, "", hl7MsgString);
}
```

*The process-Methode:*

```
private void process() throws HL7Exception, SQLException {
    // Do something...

    String sql = "BEGIN save_patient_data(?,?,?,?,?,?,?); END;";

    CallableStatement stmt = (CallableStatement) con.prepareCall(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, ...);
    // ...

    stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    stmt.execute(); 
    // ... 
    stmt.close();

    // More databse stored procedure can be called ...
}
```

*Connection Pool Settingts:*

```
Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 10 Connections
Maximum Pool Size: 60 Connections
Pool Resize Quantity: 2 Connections
Idle Timeout: 600 Seconds
Max Wait Time: 0 Milliseconds

Validate At Most Once: 0 Seconds
Connection Leak Timeout: 10 Seconds
Connection Leak Reclaim: enabled
Statement Leak Timeout: 6 Seconds
Statement Leak Reclaim: enabled
Creation Retry Attempts: 0
Retry Interval: 10 Seconds

Connection Validation: Required
Validation Method: meta-data
```

The database IDLE-Timeout setting is "**UNLIMITED**".

*Notcie:*
The exception occurred either when to call "con.prepareCall(sql);" (must not be at the first time) or when I try to commit the connection or later when to try to turn autocommit on.

Does any body know the reason or what is the best way to debug the application to find it out?

Thank you.

---

***Edit:***
Maybe it's important:
I can find in the server log many warnings about connection leaks:

```
2014-07-28T14:49:17.961+0200|Warnung: A potential connection leak detected for connection pool OraclePool. The stack trace of the thread is provided below : 
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.setResourceStateToBusy(ConnectionPool.java:324)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResourceFromPool(ConnectionPool.java:758)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getUnenlistedResource(ConnectionPool.java:632)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.AssocWithThreadResourcePool.getUnenlistedResource(AssocWithThreadResourcePool.java:200)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:526)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
de.mydomain.myproject.utilities.Database.getConnection(Database.java:17)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have connection leak reclaim enabled and the connection leak timeout is 10 seconds. This means that if you hold onto a logical connection for longer than 10 seconds, it is forcibly revoked and closed by the connection pool manager (and the physical connection is returned to the connection pool). Subsequent attempts to use the logical connection will result in a `SQLException` as the connection is closed.

Find out which operation takes longer than 10 seconds and try to reduce the time it takes **or** configure a longer connection leak timeout (10 seconds is IMHO a bit short for connection leak detection). The same BTW applies to your statement leak detection (6 seconds is also pretty short).

Comment: A Good Idea. I'll turn off the connection leak detection and try again.

Comment: I tried to debug how long time (milliseconds) it need to throw the SQLException: 142, 8129, 533, 71, 83, 915 ... So I don't think that the 10 seconds are to short :( any other ideas?

Comment: @user3608395 Did you time from obtaining the connection until the exception (also 8192 ms is pretty close to 10 seconds)? In any case, the logging you include also says a connection leak was detected (note that this detection is simply based on how long the connection was open, it applies no further 'intelligence').

Comment: The connection and steatment leak timeout and reclam are off. But the problem still remain unaffected!

Comment: @user3608395 Does your log still contain connection leak warnings? Also make sure you don't store the connection is local to the method and not stored in an instance variable.

Comment: The log doesn't contains any connection leak warings anymore. What you mean with "don't store the connection..." I do ` con = Database.getConnection();`and the con-variable will sets for every new request! Thank you